# Why two parallel branches cannot be displayed concurrently using EGit?

Tags: git, egit

I have three branches: `master`, `b1`, and `b2`.

Why `b1` and `b2` cannot be displayed concurrently using EGit?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there is a little button at the right side of the History View in Eclipse:[image] (Show all Branches and Tags). By clicking that, all the branches will be shown at the same time.

[image]

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood your question. +1